# How to improve hack deadlift lock out?

Tags: deadlifts

I am trying to do the barbell hack squat, but it seems my lock out is really bad. The main problem is that, the barbell drives into the knee joint making it difficult to straighten. It turns into a situation where I first straighten out at the hips, then the knees. Pictures:

> [image]

This leads to what seems to be an awkward movement pattern.

How to improve? Does this even need improving?

Comment: Maybe you're going too heavy too soon? You should try to perfect the technique before loading it up with what seems like 100kg

Comment: 125 kg it is@Luciano

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I tried various adjustments to this motion and it seems so the key in improving form would be to increase the knee bend more. Here is a [video](https://youtube.com/shorts/yUuImYb-ew4?si=xl6fC6Nj0a3GTJuv) I made documenting variations.

Here is all I tried:

1. Reduce how much the barbell is pulled towards me
2. Do it on defecit (multipile levels)
3. Narrow grip while on defecit
4. Improve hip lock out speed
5. Stiff legged (less knee bend)

I notice that on defecit variation of hack deadlift, I was able to achieve more knee bend and the form "looked better". Looking at other people on youtube who have attempted this exercise. Eg: [ThomasMorgantraining](https://youtube.com/shorts/x-GFgBdqQPM?si=y2oyCqDtGxy19HCr), [range of strength](https://youtube.com/shorts/H5BLOKUiBWQ?si=SB1xc42adPe6XnfX) and various others which can easily be found from googling.